# Fill empty time slots

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need to build a schedule, there is an array with data:
1.json.schedule_day
Here is the code that builds the schedule output:

```
            html  = '<div class="calendar px-4 owl-carousel owl-theme d-flex">';
            for (var i = 0; i < json.schedule_date.length; i++) {
                html += '<div class="item mb-2 text-center">';
                html += '  <div class="mb-2 small">';
                html += '   <p class="m-0">' + json['schedule_date'][i]['weekday_name'] + '</p>';
                html += '  <p class="m-0 text-muted">' + json['schedule_date'][i]['day'] + '</p>';
                html += '  </div>';
                html += '  <div class="slots d-flex flex-column">';
                    $.each(json['schedule_date'][i]['slots'], function(i, slot) {
                        if (i > 2) {
                            var $expanded = 'expanded d-none'
                        }   
                    
                        html += '  <button data-date-time="' + slot.datetime + '" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-booking mb-2 p-1 ' + $expanded + '" >' + slot.time + '</button>';
                        
                    });
                
                html += '  </div>';
                html += '</div>';
            }
            html += '</div>';
```

As a result, I get a schedule and everything is fine

[schedule_now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NogUO.png)

But you need to fill in the empty time slots (-) to get it like this:

[schedule_empty_slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWqVq.png)

here is an example of my json.schedule_day

```
  [
  {
    "date": "2020-07-27",
    "day": "27 Июл",
    "weekday_name": "Пн",
    "slots": [
      {
        "time": "19:57",
        "datetime": "2020-07-27 19:57",
        "booked": false
      },
      {
        "time": "20:27"
      },
      {
        "time": "20:57"
      },
      {
        "time": "21:27"
      },
      {
        "time": "21:57"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried filling the empty slots with whitespace?

Comment: I do not understand how to do this, josn does not give me the number of empty lines, I think I need to calculate the maximum length of json.slot and somehow insert it for all days